# How to dynamically switch between comparing Less Than, Greater Than, or Equal To?

Tags: c#

Basically I am giving the user an option to filter a set of files based on thier size.

The user picks a comparison type (Greater Than, Less Than, Equal To) from a drop down list, and then enters a size, in bytes, to compare to.  This is what I have so far:

```
switch (cmboCompareType.SelectedText)
{
    case "Greater Than":
        fileOK = fi[i].Length > int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text);
        break;
    case "Less Than":
        fileOK = fi[i].Length < int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text);
        break;
    case "Equal To":
        fileOK = fi[i].Length == int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text);
        break;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this sort of comparison without repeating so much code in C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int value = int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text);
int len = fi[i].Length;

switch (cmboCompareType.SelectedText)
{
    case "Greater Than": fileOK = len > value; break;
    case "Less Than": fileOK = len < value; break;
    case "Equal To": fileOK = len == value; break;
}
```

TADA! Less repetition. ;P

Comment: well that part was obvious.  I was looking for more of a "dynamic" comparison.

Comment: Well, you didn't ask for a dynamic comparison...you just asked for less repetition. I was trying to make a point. ;P

Comment: Well, the title does say "how to DYNAMICALLY switch..."  Though I have to admit, this one is the most simplistic, and probably the most "elegant" of all answers so far.

Comment: Although I like Jon Skeet's solution as well, I give you +1 for keeping it simple.

Comment: Oh, I missed the title. Dynamically or not, I kind of like how concise and to the point my solution was. Overall, line-for-line, I think it has a greater return on investment. :D

Comment: +1 for "TADA!" at the end.  You made me chuckle, good sir. :D

Comment: @JustLoren: Glad you enjoyed it. :D

Comment: Since I guess the level of "dynamic" I was looking for isn't really possible in C#, I prefer this one overall due to its clarity and brevity.

Answer (score 20):

Two options:

1. Use CompareTo and Sign:

```cs
int requiredSign;
switch (cmboCompareType.SelectedText)
{
   case "Greater Than": requiredSign = 1; break;
   case "Less Than": requiredSign = -1; break;
   case "Equal To": requiredSign = 0; break;
   default: throw new ArgumentException();
}
fileOK = Math.Sign(fi[i].Length.Compare(txtByteValue.Text)) == requiredSign;
```

2. Use a delegate:

```cs
static readonly Func<int, int, bool> GreaterThan = (x, y) => x > y;
static readonly Func<int, int, bool> LessThan = (x, y) => x < y;
static readonly Func<int, int, bool> Equal = (x, y) => x == y;
...

Func<int, int, bool> comparison;
switch (cmboCompareType.SelectedText)
{
   case "Greater Than": comparison = GreaterThan; break;
   case "Less Than": comparison = LessThan; break;
   case "Equal To": comparison = Equal; break;
   default: throw new ArgumentException();
}
fileOK = comparison(fi[i].Length, int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text));
```

Comment: +1 for the delegate option. Cures the DRY problem with the original code without sacrificing readability.

Comment: +1: dynamically selecting delegates, rather than particular values, is an underappreciated design pattern. Its also more extensible than the Math.Sign approach: if the OP adds more items to his dropdown, he can modified the code very easily to retrieve the appropriate comparator from a Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>>.

Comment: I like option 2 better as well. The sign one was more of an "ooh, that would work too" option :)

Comment: While I always enjoy the mind-expanding answers of John skeet, I think both these solutions would be overkill in this scenario.  It was a tough call but I think I will accept the more simple answer.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a fan of case statements, same thing though, just another way.

```
var fileOK = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>>
    (StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        { "Greater Than", (x, y) => x > y },
        { "Less Than", (x, y) => x < y },
        { "Equal To", (x, y) => x == y }
    }[cmboCompareType.SelectedText](fi.Length, int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int actual = Math.Sign(fi[i].Length.CompareTo(int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text)));
int expected;

switch (cmboCompareType.SelectedText)
{
    case "Greater Than": expected = +1; break;
    case "Less Than":    expected = -1; break;
    case "Equal To":     expected =  0; break;
}

fileOK = (actual == expected);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a map, you can use something like:

```
private int CompareOp(string Text)
{
    switch (cmboCompareType.SelectedText)
    {
        case "Greater Than": 
            return 1;
        case "Less Than": 
            return -1;
        case "Equal To": 
            return 0;
    }
}

// In your method:
fileOK = (fi[i].Length.CompareTo(value) == CompareOp(cmboCompareType.SelectedText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension method on int

```
public static int Compare(this int a, int b, string compareType)
{
    switch (CompareType)
    {
        case "Greater Than":
            return fi[i].Length > int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text);
            break;
        case "Less Than":
            return fi[i].Length < int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text);
            break;
        case "Equal To":
            return fi[i].Length == int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text);
            break;
    }
}
```

and then use it as:

```
fileOK = fi[i].Length.Compare(int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text), cmboCompareType.SelectedTex);
```

Comment: Does not address the "Don't Repeat Yourself" issue

Comment: @Nathan: it depends on how often this is used.  the extension method will show up on every int so if this comparison is being done in many different places, then the Compare method is implemented only once and used everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add the values -1, 0, 1 to the value property of each combo box item and then the code would look like:

```
fileOK = fi[i].Length.CompareTo(int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text) == cmboCompareType.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Ya thats the thought process that led me to the answer I just added. But instead of adding values, I just offset the index by one.

Answer (score 0):

My own idea, inspired by the solutions that used Math.Sign().  Since the drop down box has three values, which will have an index of 0,1,and 2,  I could subtract 1 to get -1,0,1, then use that to compare with the sign, as such:

```
int sign = Math.Sign(fi[i].Length.CompareTo(int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text)));
fileOK = sign == (cmboCompareType.SelectedIndex - 1);
```

This would be dependent on the items in the listbox being put in this specific order:
Less Than
Equal To
Greater Than

And of course would only work if these are the only values that will ever be in the listbox.  Probably not the best solution, but I got a kick out of the fact that I accomplished this in only two  lines of code.

**EDIT:** Techincally I could simplify this down to a single line of code:

```
fileOk=(cmboCompareType.SelectedIndex-1) == Math.Sign(fi[i].Length.CompareTo(int.Parse(txtByteValue.Text)));
```